# Easy-to-learn language like Python, but which requires variable declaration?

Tags: python, declaration, declare, variable-declaration

Python is super easy to learn and understand; I like it for its use of keywords, lack of intricate syntax (opposite of perl, from what I've heard), and easy-to-use data structures. However, I can't stand the lack of variable declaration, because it makes it impossible to explicitly tell Python what scope you want the variable to have. Are there any languages that have all the qualities I like about Python *as well as* variable declaration, and perhaps a decent set of libraries available?

Thankslot.

Comment: Python's scope is fairly easy to deduce. I don't really see what you mean.

Comment: How does variable declaration have anything to do with scope?  If you do the "right thing" in most languages and declare where you initialize, you have exactly the same situation.

Comment: @Nick Bastin: In languages with true closures, variable declaration is used to set scope - if you declare a variable inside a function, it is readable and writeable by anything else declared inside that function (even if called later on). Python doesn't allow *assignment* to things in higher scope (except the global scope).

Comment: @Amber: of course you mean Python 2.x. Python 3.x has the [nonlocal](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/reference/simple_stmts.html#nonlocal) statement for that purpose.

Comment: @Ambers, as you said, Python doesn't allow assignment to names outside the current scope, but that is because of Python's "explicit is better" philosophy. If you want to overwrite names outside the current scope, you have to write down the namespace you're trying to change. so .. simply use mutable objects.

Comment: @Amber: To your first point, that's neither here nor there - no language gives you complete access control over scope (we don't have ACLs to define name propagation).  To your second point you're just wrong - Python allows explicit assignment to names in a higher scope (w/`nonlocal` and `global`).  Python allows exactly what the OP wants, they perhaps just don't understand it.

Comment: Apparently, the specific frustration I was having was solvable by putting the code I was using sketchy stuff like global for into a class and then referencing it from inside functions by using self.foo.

Comment: @Nick: `nonlocal` only exists in Python 3k, which is not really the current standard for most Python shops.

Comment: @Muhammad: Correct, I mean Python 2.x - it's still the most commonly used Python.

Comment: @Amber: If someone is talking about "learning python" there's certainly no reason to use 2.x, as is the same for any new project.  Also, there is no Python 3k - that term has long been replaced by *actual* software, which as of this writing is Python 3.1.2.  Python 2.x needs to die.

Answer (score 7):

Try [pychecker](http://pychecker.sourceforge.net/), [pylint](http://www.logilab.org/857), [pyflakes](http://www.logilab.org/857) or other code checking tools. They help catch errors that the interpreter doesn't complain about.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using Python with variable declarations:

```
>>> x = 0 # a global variable
>>> def fact(n): #n is a parameter
...     x = 0 # local variable declaration
...     z = 1 # declaration and initialization
...     for i in range(1, n + 1): # a loop variable is defined inline
...         z = z * i
...     return z
...     
>>> x = 5 # the global x
>>> fact(x)
120
```

Can you explain what is the problem with this? Also, like Nick Bastin said in a comment, it would help if you explain if your problem is with declaration or scope.

If your problem is with the syntax or with static typing, would the next syntax be acceptable to you?

```
def f(double x):
    return x**2-x

def integrate_f(double a, double b, int N):
    cdef int i
    cdef double s, dx
    s = 0
    dx = (b-a)/N
    for i in range(N):
        s += f(a+i*dx)
    return s * dx
```

[This syntax](http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/cythonize.html) is that of [Cython](http://www.cython.org/), a language for extending Python using compiled (C) extensions.

Answer (score 1):

C#

Here are some [code examples](http://www.csharp-examples.net/examples/).

Answer (score 0):

Try Google's [Go](http://golang.org) if you are not talking about production code.  The language is just over a year old.  It is very easy to learn as well.  This suggestion is only because you asked for *any languages*.

Otherwise, Wim Coenen's answer should simply work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a look at Perl 6, which removes the problems you described in Perl 5, but maintains the benefits, with option to even have strongly typed variables. The problem is that it's still not finished, and nobody knows when it will...

Either way you can check [dev.perl.org](http://dev.perl.org) if you are insterested.

Answer (score 0):

[Cython](http://cython.org/) is a lot like Python but has variable declaration that is like C (actually, Cython allows for a lot of stuff that is present in C).

Answer (score 0):

How about [Boo](http://boo.codehaus.org/).  CLR, very Python-like.  Static types with type inference.